# How do astronomers know what wavelength the body will emit when it is at rest?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, wavelength, doppler-effect, redshift

In the book of *The First Three Minutes* by Weinberg, at page 21, he talks about how do astronomers measure the speed of a luminous body along the line of sight by Doppler affect, i.e. the fractional change in the wavelength of the incoming light will be proportional to the speed of the body to $c$, but to use this technique, we need to know the original wavelength, i.e the wavelength of the emitted light when the body is at rest, without it we cannot talk about any increase in the wavelength, so how do astronomers get this information prior to the measurement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addition to the correct answer of @flippiefanus, consider the element sodium.

When excited at low pressure by an electric arc, sodium vapour emits a complex spectrum of discrete wavelengths, *an atomic emission spectrum*,  dominated by two intense emission lines with slightly different wavelengths:  one at $588.9950$ nanometres and the second at $589.5924$ nanometres.  If you have ever tossed some salt (or salt water) into a Bunsen burner flame, or seen a low-pressure sodium street light, you've seen these two wavelengths.

In addition, if you pass a continuous spectrum through a cloud of unexcited sodium vapour, these same two wavelengths will be strongly absorbed in an *atomic absorption spectrum*.

The two wavelengths above have been very precisely measured for sodium atoms at rest in the lab framework.  In addition, the *ratio* of the two wavelengths has been calculated: $1.00101427$.

If the sodium is moving towards or away from the observer at some unknown speed, the two emission lines will both be Doppler shifted by the same factor, *but the ratio will stay the same*!

So, if an astronomer takes a spectrum of a distant star and sees two very close, strong, emission or absorption lines, he/she will calculate the ratio of the two wavelengths.  If the result is the same as the ratio above, then the original wavelengths are known, and the observed wavelengths, via the Doppler shift, will produce a velocity of recession or approach.

Comment: What if the ratio is not the same ? is there any such chance ?

Comment: Sure, if it isn't produced by sodium!   But there are other wavelengths present in the spectrum from other elements;  something will produce a Doppler shift that explains all the wavelengths...

Answer (score 5):

Stars emit lots of different wavelengths, but there are special wavelengths associated with the absorption spectra of the elements found in stars. These are known and they are the same everywhere, even in stars that are far away from us. So all the astronomers need to do is to identify the spectra of the elements in the light coming from these stars. Then they can see how much they have shifted compared to the measured spectra that we can observe in our labs. In this way, they can determine the amount of Doppler shift.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer by flippiefanus, here is the [history of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)) showing the three minutes:

[image]

At three minures, shown on the plot, nuclei have already formed and the electrons are attracted to them to form atoms, falling down the energy levels, and being scattered away again, due to the still high energy in the plasma.  It is not until after the modern universe line that absorption lines from stars can be identified as [coming from a specific star.](http://www.indiana.edu/~geol105/images/gaia_chapter_1/visible_light_spectral_emission_.htm) .

[image: absorpti]

> The schematic diagram above shows a galactic star at the bottom left with its spectrum on the bottom right. The spectrum shows the dark absorption lines first seen by Fraunhofer. These lines can be used to identify the chemical elements in distant stars, but they also tell us the radial velocity. The other three spectra and pictures from bottom to top show a nearby galaxy, a medium distance galaxy, and a distant galaxy. The pictures on the left are negatives, of course, so the brightest parts of the galaxies are black. Notice how the pattern of absorption lines shifts to the red as the galaxies get fainter. The numbers above and below the spectra are the measured wavelengths in nm (nanometers).

I think that the statement in the book is a general astronomic statement, which belongs further in time than three minutes, as before 380.000 yrs the photons are continually interacting in a soup of atoms, and after 380.000yrs  this is the radiation seen as [cosmic microwave background r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background)adiation which has not retained spectral  information. It is the best black body curve measured.

So it is absorption spectra of specific stars that can be used in astronomy.